# Passing DTO's to service layer for CRUD operations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mapping, dto

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC Web App.
My current architecture looks like:

```
Presentation Layer <--> Service Layer <--> Data Access Layer
```

The Data Access Layer contains the EF Entity Models.
The Service Layer retrieves the EF Entity Models from the Data Access Layer and returns DTO's. 
The Presentation Layer retrieves DTO's from the Service Layer and returns ViewModels to Views.

My question is about what class I should pass to my create and update functions that reside in my service layer. For example:

Entity Models:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }     
    public string LastName { get; set; }            
    public int UserTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
}

public class UserType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }                

    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
}
```

DTO:

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }                
    public int UserTypeId { get; set; }

    //Note this "extra" field
    public string UserTypeName { get; set; }        
}
```

Service Layer functions:

```
public class UserService: IUserService
{
    public UserDTO GetUser(int userId)
    {
        //The UserType.Name is used a lot, so I'd rather include it in this one db call 
        //rather than use a separate db call to get the name based on the UserTypeId

        return _dbContext.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId)
                   .Select(u => new UserDTO 
                   {
                       Id = u.Id,
                       FirstName = u.FirstName,
                       LastName = u.LastName,
                       UserTypeId = u.UserTypeId,

                       UserTypeName = u.UserType.Name
                   }
                   .First();
    }

    //??
    public void EditUser(UserDTO userDto)
    {
        //Should I use this? Or EditUser(EditUserDTO editUserDto)...    
    }

    //??
    public void EditUser(EditUserDTO editUserDto)
    {
        //Should I use this? Or EditUser(UserDTO userDto)...   
        //Note EditUserDTO looks like UserDTO but does not have UserTypeName 
    }
}
```

You'll see my confusion is in what class to use as a parameter for EditUser(...).

- If I use `EditUser(UserDTO userDto)`, then how will other developers
  know that they **don't** need to set UserDTO.UserTypeName? They
  would only need to set UserTypeId.
- If I use `EditUser(EditUserDTO editUserDto)`, then the developer would know 
  exactly which info to set (every property in EditUserDTO). But its an extra class to maintain, and map, and work with.

Some Ideas:

1. I could have the DTO match the Entity model exactly, but then what's the point of using DTOs?
2. Instead of having a "flat" DTO, I could have a UserTypeDTO class as a property of the UserDTO. I think this would make things a little more clear, but it still wouldn't be required to be set when calling EditUser(UserDTO). *Side question: Is there any best practice as to if DTO's should be "flat" or not?*
3. Any other ideas...?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a separate DTO definition for Get and Edit operations. Then there is no possibility of a consumer trying to set something that they shouldn't be able to. So I would say use `EditUserDTO` for the EditUser method.

**Update**

To add a bit more context to my answer.

The idea of using a DTO is to abstract away your underlying DAL. There is often a lot more data stored in you Data Layer that is not returned from your Service Layer or your Entities may not have the same structure that you want to send back to a caller, so by creating a DTO you are able to hide this away. This also gives you the option that you can change your DAL and keep the public contract of your Service Layer the same so that consumers don't have to re-write their code when you change something internally.

DTO's can be flat or have hierarchy. It really depends on whether it makes sense to keep the DTO flat or have a hierarchy. Taking your example `UserDTO`, I would say that unless you are going to return the tree of UserTypes in the `UserDTO` you should keep this as a simple "flat" DTO.

Comment: I agree with all your statements about the benefit DTOs provide. And I'm tending to agree with your answer about using separate DTOs for Get and Edit. I just haven't seen any full examples like this. Most examples I see just use the same DTO, but the DTOs in the examples tend to match exactly the Entity models....
Happen to know of any examples or tutorials @Darren?

Comment: Recently I've been working on some REST APIs. As an example, the DAL returns information about a users' profile including things like score, if they are a verified user and the hashed and salted password. When the app gets a specific user profile their current score and a `bool` indicating if they are verified or not are returned, we don't return the password hash for obvious reasons. When a user edits their profile the services do not allow for them to edit their score or whether they are verified as these are by products of app usage or admin functions. So we use separate DTOs for these.

Comment: Was hoping for an online/physical example, but an anecdotal one works too  :). Yeah I definitely see how separate DTOs in that case makes sense.
I also have another question regarding DTOs if you don't mind:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382492/validating-data-in-the-service-layer-against-dtos-entity-models-or-something-e