# Validating data in the service layer against DTOs, Entity Models, or something else?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, dto, service-layer

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project. In the project I have a service layer that accepts DTOs for CRUD operations. When I need to validate business logic, should the validator accept DTOs, Entity Models, or something else entirely?

For example:

```
public class ProductService: IProductService
{
    public ValidationResult CreateProduct(ProductDTO productDto)
    {
       //call productValidator.Validate(productDto) on the DTO here?

        Product productEntityModel = mapper.Map<Product>(productDto);

        //or, call productValidator.Validate(productEntityModel) on the Entity model here?

        if(validationResult.Valid)
        {
            _dbContext.Products.Add(productEntityModel);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        return validationResult
    }
}
```

Some thoughts:

- I've seen online some talk of creating a POCO which can have validation logic (rather than using a validation service) and even other business logic inside of it. This makes sense, but it is yet one more "representaion" of a product that has to be managed and maintained.
- Validating against the DTO maybe seems a little more reasonable since that is that the caller is sending to the service?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I use DTO approach and have a question. How would you return a validation error when your method signature is `List<History> ListHistory(int userId, string specialString)` ?

Answer (score 0):

> When I need to validate business logic, should the validator accept
>   DTOs, Entity Models, or something else entirely?

Normally, we perform validation in `ViewModel` class using `DataAnnotations`, so that we can return user friendly `ModelError`. For example,

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
   [Display(Name = "Username")]
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your username.")]
   public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      ...
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "User is not authorized!");
   }
   ...
}
```

Although you can validate some business logic inside `ProductService`, you cannot return MVC `ModelError`, since Service/Repository Layer should not depends on ASP.NET MVC (or any UI components).

Most of the error inside Service/Repository Layer are unexpected error instead of user error. We norammly log those error in NLog or Log4Net, and redirect user to custom error page.

Comment: I should have specified deep/complex logic that requires database access, not simple validation like required fields. For example, validating that another product with the same name does not already exist in the database.

Comment: I *personally* like to keep business logic inside action method. I like my service/repository layer as clean as possible. Look at this one of the best open source shopping cart based on ASP.NET MVC - [Create Action Method](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/develop/src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Areas/Admin/Controllers/CustomerController.cs#L845) and [InsertCustomer method](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/develop/src/Libraries/Nop.Services/Customers/CustomerService.cs#L483) inside Repository/Service class.

Comment: Ah, I personally like the business logic inside either the Service or Core project, and not the web/presentation project. In case another Presentation layer needs to be added or a separate API needs to be used, I don't want to have to duplicate the logic.

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer. It seems like you have ready make a decision; I'll say go for it.